# Storing output of a bash script for reuse

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I made a script [Wall-d](https://github.com/ronniedroid/Wall-d) that sets the wallpaper for x. I want to save the output (the chosen Wallpaper and other options) in a variable that I can reuse later with a flag

For example,

```
xwallpaper --$option $wall
```

and the result is

```
xwallpaper --zoom $HOME/Pictures/mountain.png
```

Hoe can I store this info so that I can later use a flag to restore the last set wallpaper when I restart x, for example
In .xinitrc

```
Wall-d -r
```

should restore the last set wallpaper.

Hope I'm clear in what I'm asking. my Github repo for Wall-d is linked above if you need to see the code

Thank you in advance

PS: Please note that my question is not how to make the flag -r, but rather how to store the last output of the script.

Comment: Storing it to the config file is not the option?

Comment: @Abelisto now I use sed to replace a string in another shell script which gets executed on start-up. Is this what you mean by config?

Comment: `printf "otpion=%s\nwall=%s\n" $option $wall > ~/.config/Wall-d.conf` and at start `. ~/.config/Wall-d.conf` - something like this.

Comment: @Abelisto this could work, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Abelisto I had time to think about it, this is not what I desire.